# How to get a 00:00:00 instead of 12:00:00 AM?

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2003 Database

Table1

```
Intime   Outtime  WorkTime OverTime

08:00:00 19:00:00 09:00:00 02:00:00
09:00:00 18:23:23 09:00:00 00:23:23
15:00:00  -----   00:00:00 00:00:00
09:00:00 18:00:00 09:00:00 00:00:00
```

Intime, Outtime, Work time, overtime data type is text

```
From 09:00:00 to 18:00:00 - It will come in Work time
Before 09:00:00, after 18:00:00 – It will come in overtime
```

My query.

```
SELECT PERSONID,
       CARDEVENTDATE,
       INTIME,
       OUTTIME,
       (IIF(OUTTIME = 'No Punchout', '00:00:00', WorkTime)) AS WorkedTime,
       (IIF(OUTTIME = 'No Punchout', '00:00:00', OverTime)) AS OverdutyTime,
       Latecome,
       (IIF(OUTTIME = 'No Punchout', '', EarlyLeave)) AS EarlyLeave
FROM
       (SELECT PERSONID,
               CARDEVENTDATE,
               INTIME,
               (IIF(OUTTIME = INTIME, 'No PunchOut', OUTTIME)) AS OUTTIME,
               (Format(IIf(CLng(OutTime) > 180000, 
                           CDate('18:00:00'), 
                           CDate(Format(OutTime, '00:00:00'))) 
                       - IIf(CLng(InTime) < 90000, 
                           CDate('09:00:00'), 
                           CDate(Format(InTime, '00:00:00'))),
                       'hh:nn:ss')) AS WorkTime,
               (Format(IIf(CLng(InTime) < 90000, 
                           CDate('09:00:00') 
                           - CDate(Format(InTime, '00:00:00')), 0) 
                       + IIf(CLng(OutTime) > 180000, 
                           CDate(Format(OutTime, '00:00:00')) 
                           - CDate('18:00:00'), 0), 
                       'hh:nn:ss')) AS OverTime,
               (Format(IIf(CLng(Intime) > 090000, 
                           CDate(Format(Intime, '00:00:00'))) 
                       - IIf(90000, CDate('09:00:00'), 
                           CDate(Format(InTime, '00:00:00'))), 
                       'hh:nn:ss')) AS LateCome,
               (Format(IIf(180000, 
                           CDate('18:00:00'), 
                           CDate(Format(outtime, '00:00:00'))) 
                       - IIf(CLng(Outtime) < 180000, 
                           CDate(Format(Outtime, '00:00:00'))), 
                       'hh:nn:ss')) AS EarlyLeave
               (SELECT  T_PERSON.PERSONID,
                        T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE,
                        MIN(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS INTIME,
                        MAX(T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTTIME) AS OUTTIME
               FROM     T_PERSON
                        INNER JOIN T_CARDEVENT
                        ON       T_PERSON.PERSONID = T_CARDEVENT.PERSONID
               GROUP BY T_PERSON.PERSONID,
                        T_CARDEVENT.CARDEVENTDATE
               )
       )
```

Above query is Correctly Working in my system.

But when I use the query in client system, it showing like this…

Table1

```
Intime   Outtime  WorkTime    OverTime

08:00:00 19:00:00 09:00:00 AM 02:00:00 AM
09:00:00 18:23:23 09:00:00 AM 12:23:23 AM
15:00:00  -----   12:00:00 AM 00:00:00 AM
09:00:00 18:00:00 09:00:00 AM 12:00:00 AM
```

It is displaying 12:00:00 AM Instead of 00:00:00 and also displaying 12:23:23 instead of 00:00:00.

If it is 00 then it is displaying 12:00:00 AM.

Clients Using Access 2007 Database. There is not Access 2003 or Access 2007 Problem. 
Why worktime and Overtime is displaying like 12:00:00 AM.  I copied the client database and check the database in my System. Work Time and Over Time is correctly displaying.

Please can any one help to solve my problem.

Comment: convert to SQL 2005 Express and use CONVERT() ... how simple can it be? you will eventually have problems in Access (MS says BIG performance problem with tables over 35000 rows)... please change it, and post the question again if you find any other trouble.

Comment: The client might not want Express installed or the specification of the job might say has to be in access. I know you can use access as a front-end and use SQL as a bank-end but as I said this may not be an option.

Comment: Your query contains three SELECTs but only two FROMs, so I find it hard to believe it is Correctly Working in your system. There seems to be something missing after "As EarlyLeave".

Comment: @balexandre: if I could vote down comments, I would. Your comment is COMPLETELY unrealistic and unhelpful.

Comment: This is a display issue. How are you displaying the data? Once that is answered, you can figure out how to FORMAT the display. Format(DateTimeValue, ""hh:nn:ss am/pm") will display in 24:00 time, whereas since you're not formatting the output, so it's defaulting to the system settings and displaying in the equivalent of Format(DateTimeValue, ""hh:nn:ss AM/PM"). Again, it's a DISPLAY issue, not a SQL issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the way your system displays time.

Comment: How to Change the System Display Time

Comment: WinXP Control Panel > Regional And Language Options >Customize > Time
I could be wrong.

Comment: That's not a valid answer since there may be dependencies in other apps.

Comment: Mr. Antony Is working Fine. Time is displaying Correctly. Thankyou